# SQL proper usage of AND and FROM

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out exactly how to use FROM properly. So lets take for example I have a table like so:

```
STUDENT(*snum:  integer,sname: string,deptid:integer,slevel:string,age:integer)     
ENROLLED(*snum:integer, *cname: string)
```

I am trying to count the number of students that are enrolled in a class that are under the age of 21. Can anyone explain why it is returning 0? What I think I am doing is looking an enrolled then comparing the class name with the class I am looking for it. I then check if there is a student that is currently enrolled in that class, and if there is I then check if the age is below 21. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
  ENROLLED e,
  STUDENT s
WHERE
  e.cname='ENG101'
  AND e.snum=s.snum
  AND s.age < 21;
```

Sample Data:
insert into ENROLLED values (1234,'ENG400');
insert into STUDENT values (1234,'T.Banks',3,'SR',18);

Comment: Perhaps there are no students under 21 enrolled in the ENG101 course.

Comment: The query looks ok. Can you post a data sample of each table which would demonstrate the problem? Set it up over at http://sqlfiddle.com if you can

Comment: Without seeing the data, this is impossible to answer. The query looks relatively fine (although this style of join is almost never used in practice), but there may just be no students in the data with those criteria.

Comment: @Gordon: Or there are no students of any age enrolled in 'ENG101'.

Comment: I should have mentioned that there is data that fits that criteria. I think something might be wrong with my SQL. I was doing really simple commands and every time I would try to do FROM table a, table b it wouldn't post any results. If I just do it from 1 table it works. Here is a sample of the data. 
insert into ENROLLED values (1234,'ENG400');
insert into STUDENT values (1234,'T.Banks',3,'SR',18);

Comment: It works, if I use `ENG101` as in your SQL query instead of `ENG400` in your sample row... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68cb4/4

Comment: Your sample data is for ENG400, while your questions uses ENG101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the query differently:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) EnrolledStudents
FROM
    ENROLLED e
    INNER JOIN
    STUDENT s
    ON
        e.snum = s.snum
WHERE
    e.cname = 'ENG101'
    AND
    s.age < 21;
```

And maybe try this to see if one of your statements in the WHERE is causing the problem:

```
SELECT
    e.cname,
    s.age,
    COUNT(*) EnrolledStudents
FROM
    ENROLLED e
    INNER JOIN
    STUDENT s
    ON
        e.snum = s.snum
GROUP BY
    e.cname,
    s.age;
```

My bet though is that either 'ENG101' is incorrect or there are no student ages in ENG101 < 21.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use "INNER JOIN" first, like the comment above. Actually SQL will deal with JOIN first and use where condition as a filter to select appropriate rows in the joined table. So result of "A join B on A.id=B.id where condition" is quite different from "where condition and A.id=B.id", the first condition in where fails and no need to do others.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. In an inner join these are identical. In an outer join, yes it makes a difference.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Thanks for your kindly remind, it's late in my city, I will check it tomorrow.